# How grained should microservices be (in this case)?

Tags: microservices

I'm working on a big project with easily defined boundaries and domains.

The project includes:

- Portal (news, articles, encyclopedia, users)
- Forum (threads, posts, users)
- Chat (messages, users)

Essentially, if I used the `macroservice` architecture - I would create 3 cross-communicating services (as listed above) and just have them replicate users, as it's the only shared resource.

.. but I know for a fact that according to `microservices` architecture - each and every thing in parenthesis (news, threads, messages, users ..) should be a separate service - which will make the whole project more complex and bigger in terms of data - as now I'll also have to replicate `user` on `news`, `articles`, `encyclopedia`, `threads`, `posts` and `messages` services - essentially having 7 copies of the user (granted, with less columns in most services, but still).

Can someone explain to me which of the approaches to services is better? Macro or micro?

Comment: Probably Mono. What arguments do you have for creating 3 cross-communicating services? Why don't the same arguments apply for creating 7 cross-communicating services?

Comment: @RikD Let's see.
For macroservices approach (3 bigger services): less data replication, less cross-service communication, ability to use `portal`, `forum` or `chat` even if other services fail, lower scalability as I can't scale just the `users` service by adding another instance of `users` as it's bundled into `portal`.
For microservices approach (7 smaller services): more data replication, more cross-service communication, ability to browse `encyclopedia` when `articles` or `news` are down (same goes for other services there), ability to scale just the specific service.

Comment: So you have some arguments for each approach. I can think of a few more, but if this is what's important for you, that's fine. Why would we, contributors to this website, be able to weigh these arguments better than you can?

Comment: @RikD because I know pros and cons of both approaches but don't know which one would be better for the longer run.

Comment: You should update your question, because that's really relevant. What's important in the long run can be quite different from what's important now. For example, if you currently don't have anything, it can be really beneficial to quickly create a monolithic prototype and find out what your users value the most in your system and evolve from there. If you already have a system and the challenge is scaling it up with multiple development teams and high load, the macro or microservice discussion becomes relevant. But to be honest, when you arrive at that point, you probably won't be asking here.

Comment: The user database should also be an own microservice. That way you don't need to replicate the user data.

Comment: @Philipp what you just said is so wrong on so many levels.
So, I should deliberately implement a single point of failure?

Comment: @JCode: the user authentication should be its own microservice, otherwise people will have to keep logging into your application as they move between different pages, and that's not a great user experience. The user component on each microservice on the other hand, should just be a slim token cache, and not provide a full user service with logins and stuffs. Each microservice can then maintain its own slice of user data if that slice is only relevant for one service, but if there's cross-service data, they'll need to be stored in a shared place, and the user service is a natural place for it.

Comment: @LieRyan Actually, I was planning on using GraphQL API with schemastitching as access layer - then I only need AuthMiddleware for requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottom Line Up Front:** The more cross communication each service needs to do, the less likely that you've properly defined the correct boundaries.

When decomposing microservices, you want to minimize the direct dependencies between them.  That is done in many different ways:

- The integration is done in the front-end (i.e. Single Page App) or a near-front-end layer (GraphQL layer)
- All relevant user claims are built into the user's session token

  - The session token needs to be tamper evident (i.e. signed)
  - Easily validated independently
  - That token should be provided with every call to every service
- Data references are often transmitted as URLs

With the above requirements on the User session token, it's understandable that [JWT](https://jwt.io) is one of the most common standards for user tokens--particularly since almost every language used for microservices supports parsing and validating those tokens.  By shifting the requirement of user identification to the session token, you remove almost all reasons to need to look up user information.  That leaves your `user` service to take on the role of managing user information and handling token management.  Your single page app, stores the session token and submits it with the `Authentication` HTTP header for every call to a microservice.  In this case, this identifies `user` service as it's own independent service, and removes "user" from the list of parentheses on the initial list of microservices.

With hierarchical information like "Threads" and "Posts" for your `forum` srevice, you have to decide if the information is truly independent or not.  If the concept of "Posts" was going to be re-used for more than just "Threads", you might have an argument to separate the two.  However, I would most likely treat them as part of the same service until you have a documented reason to separate them.

As you break down the list of services you need to implement, you may find that `portal` is not a microservice and just a feature for the Single-Page-App (SPA).

It seems that your services would be truly independent if you adopted a different scheme for user management, such as the JWT tokens.  You may not even need to write the `user` service if you intend on using managed identity solutions like AWS Cognito which can generate the tokens for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the additional complexity required by introducing a microservice architecture is only justified when

- you are expecting a requirement to scale up the services independently, or
- you want to make it possible to develop and deploy the services independently (maybe in parallel by different persons or teams)

So if you have one of the requirements above, go for microservices. If not, you probably won't need it.

(Of course, this is just a general rule of thumb. There may be more driving factors to consider, but as a first shot this approach may serve you well.)

Comment: This is a quite simple explanation to follow, thank you!

Comment: @docbrown, having lived in the world of microservices for the past couple years or so, I can agree with your sentiment.  There is one more reason to go with microservices--if you do it right--and that is minimizing the blast radius of failure.  For example, if the `forum` service goes down, that's only one feature out of 6-7 that is affected.

Comment: Something to consider is that none of the big services you know of know started on microservices.  They started with something else, and scaled it as far as they could, until the cost of developing microservices was worth the investment.  This goes for Twitter, Amazon store front, Facebook, etc.  Based on the architecture diagrams for Stack Exchange, it still isn't microservice based: https://stackexchange.com/performance

Answer (score 1):

The most common advice when deciding this is that you should start your application as a monolithic service and then evolve it to microservice over time as you learn the pain points of your application. It's generally a lot easier to develop and manage a monolithic service than a microservice until you get to a certain scalability point when microservice starts to make more sense.

You would not know what would benefit from microservice separation until you reached that point. Don't try to start a project by designing seven microservices simultaneously; that's overengineering and you'll never reach the market if you follow that path. You don't want the additional complexity of managing microservices unless the benefit outweighs the cost.

So the answer to your title question "how grained should microservices be?" is that it should be as coarse as you can afford.